# Browser doesn't show login prompt

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, tomcat, authentication

I have an app running on TomEE besides Apache HTTP Server. 
Calling any service method shows me

```
HTTP Status 401 -
type Status report
message
description This request requires HTTP authentication.
Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/7.0.47 (1.6.0)
```

Specific tomcat role is defined in tomcat-users.xml and relatively allowed in the web-service.
How to set it(browser or whatever) to ask for login and password?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved: we need to update vhost.conf (apache side), as we use two different instances of service, and they, relatively should use different authentication types: so, instead of one `<Location>` section we separated it into two different and changed parameter `"Header unset WWW-Authenticate`" inside `Location` sections

```
   <Location /api>
        ProxyPass  http://localhost:8080/backend/api
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/backend/api
        Header unset WWW-Authenticate
    </Location>
    <Location /api2 >
      ProxyPass  http://localhost:8180/backend2/api2
      ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8180/backend2/api2
    </Location>
```